# Not able to slice the array using `prev` and `next` arrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a array values, which need to slice and show in the web page. i have `prev` and `next` arrows, according to the array navigation i am slicing the array values. this is work when i use `next` arrow. but not working with `prev` array.

Logically i made some mistake here. as well when the `next` or `prev` goes more than array length or less than array length i am applying `opacity` and disabling the button.

any one correct me my mistake here?

here is my code :

```js
var num = 0;
  var myArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"];
  var batch = 5;
  var value = 0;
  
  var showArray = function (num) {
    
    var required = myArray.slice(value, (batch+value));
    console.log(required, num);
    
    value += 5;
    
  }
  
  showArray(0);
  
  function add(amount) {
    num = (num + myArray.length - batch + amount) % myArray.length + batch;
    showArray(num);
  }

 $('#next-arrow').click(function(e){
   
   if(value >= myArray.length) {
     $(e.target).css({ opacity:0.5 });
     return
   }
   $(e.target).css({ opacity:1});
   add(batch)
   
   
 }); 
 $('#prev-arrow').click(function(e){
   
   if(value <= myArray.length) {
     $(e.target).css({ opacity:0.5 });
     return
   }
   
   $(e.target).css({ opacity:1});
   add(-batch)
   
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="container">
      
      <a href="#" id="prev-arrow">Previous</a>
      <a href="#" id="next-arrow">Next</a>
      
    </div>
```

Comment: For one thing, in `showArray()`, you always **add** 5 to `value`.

Comment: `showArray()` takes a parameter `num` but all it does with it is log it to the console.

Comment: And  `if(value <= myArray.length)` seems to be strange in your `#prev-arrow` click event.

Comment: I have added the `live demo` link in my question. any one update your other idea there?

Comment: you are fetching 5 element each time.Is this slot is fixed?

Comment: Yes, that is fixed. may the slot number may change in future, but that will be fixed. ( say instead of 5 it will be 3 or 6..)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var num = 0;
  var myArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"];
  var batch = 5;
  var nextIndex = 0;
  var prevIndex = 0;

  var showArray = function (boolShowPrev) {

        var required;

        if(boolShowPrev){

            console.log("==",nextIndex, nextIndex+batch);
            required = myArray.slice(nextIndex, nextIndex+batch);    
            console.log(required)
            nextIndex += 5; 
            prevIndex -= 5;
         }else{
            if(nextIndex >= myArray.length){

                prevIndex=batch- (nextIndex-myArray.length);
                required = myArray.slice(-prevIndex);
                console.log(required);

                nextIndex -= 5; 
            }else{

                console.log("prev",-batch-prevIndex,-prevIndex)    
                required = myArray.slice(-batch-prevIndex,-prevIndex);
                console.log(required);
                prevIndex +=batch;
                nextIndex -= 5;
            }


        }


  }

  showArray(true);

 $('#next-arrow').click(function(e){

   if(nextIndex >= myArray.length) {
     $(e.target).css({ opacity:0.5 });
     return
   }
   $(e.target).css({ opacity:1});
   showArray(true)


 }); 
 $('#prev-arrow').click(function(e){

   if(prevIndex >= myArray.length) {
     $(e.target).css({ opacity:0.5 });
     return
   }

   $(e.target).css({ opacity:1});
   showArray(false)

 });

})
```

Please refer this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HII5awtPoi0qlWKKZZUW?p=preview)